# gettext character encoding

Tags: c++, gettext

I have the following [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) .po file, which has been translated from a .pot file. I am working on a Linux system ([openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) if it matters), running gettext 0.17.

```
# 
#   <translate@transme.de>, 2011
# transer <translate@transme.de>, 2011
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: transtest\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-05-24 22:47+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2011-05-30 23:03+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: German (Germany)\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1)\n"

#: transtest.cpp:12
msgid "Min Size"
msgstr "Min Größe"
```

Now, when I create the .mo file via

```
msgfmt -c transtest_de_DE.po -o transtest.mo
```

I then check the encoding with the "file" command,

```
file --mime transtest_de_DE.po
transtest_de_DE.po: text/x-po; charset=utf-8
```

and then install it to my locale folder and run the program after exporting `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE`, I end up with garbage where the two non-ASCII chars are.

If I set my terminal encoding to [ISO-8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2), rather than [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), then I see the two characters correctly.

Looking inside the generated .mo file with a text editor the file appears to be in UTF-8 as well (I can see the symbols if I set my editor encoding to UTF-8).

The program is very simple, and it looks like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
const char *PROGRAM_NAME="transtest";

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain( PROGRAM_NAME, "/usr/share/locale" );
    textdomain( PROGRAM_NAME );
    cerr << gettext("Min Size") << endl;
}
```

I am installing the .mo file to `/usr/share/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/transstest.mo`, and I have exported `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` as "de_DE".

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE; echo $LANG
de_DE
de_DE
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is gettext giving me the wrong encoding (ISO-8859-2) for my strings, rather than the requested (in the .po file) UTF-8?

#### Edit:

The solution was in Stack Overflow question *[Can't make (UTF-8) traditional Chinese character to work in PHP gettext extension (.po and .mo files created in poEdit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264740/cant-make-utf-8-traditional-chinese-character-to-work-in-php-gettext-extension)* and it appears that I needed to explicitly call

```
bind_textdomain_codeset(PROGRAM_NAME, "utf-8");
```

The final program looks like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
const char *PROGRAM_NAME="transtest";

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain( PROGRAM_NAME, "/usr/share/locale" );
    bind_textdomain_codeset(PROGRAM_NAME, "utf-8");
    textdomain( PROGRAM_NAME );
    cerr << gettext("Min Size") << endl;
}
```

No changes to any of my gettext files were needed.

Comment: I'm mighty shaky on locales, but if you wanted UTF-8 strings, shouldn't you set your `LANG=de_DE.utf8`?

Comment: I just tried that, but it does not seem to make any difference, even if I alter the .mo install location.

Anyway, I have specified it in the .po file, which I would have thought gave gettext all the info it needs.

Comment: Oh man. five hours later I find this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264740/cant-make-utf-8-traditional-chinese-character-to-work-in-php-gettext-extension. Oh well, problem solved... sorry for the noise!

Comment: @CodeT, if that post actually provides the information you need to solve the problem, _please_ summarize its contents in an answer here and accept it. :) I don't immediately see how that answer would be useful to you, so hopefully your answer can help others in the future.

Comment: how do I accept an answer in the other URL?? The answer was that I needed to set the output text format explicitly using the bind_textdomain_codeset function, or gettext defaulted to whatever it felt like, which is not UTF-8 -- despite what I say in my .po file

Comment: @CodeT, just re-write that last comment into an answer on _this_ question, maybe copy in the code that _works_, and then click the accept mark. :) A link to the other question/answer might be kind, but not really necessary since it's already in the comments.

Comment: This site won't let me answer my question as i don't have enough "rep" or somesuch. I just put it in as an edit.

Comment: @CodeT, my last comment was quite wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186 Looks like you need to wait an eternity (aka 8 hours). Sorry.

Comment: @CodeT: You should be able to move your solution down to an answer now so we can get this off the unanswered list.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `LC_CTYPE=de_DE` (or `LANG`), programs are *supposed* to output ISO-8859-1 (note, 1, not 2), so if you have that and your terminal is set to utf-8, it's simply wrong. The correct locale for utf-8 is `de_DE.utf-8`.

Using `bind_textdomain_codeset` is wrong in your case. `bind_textdomain_codeset` is used if you want to work in fixed encoding internally, like e.g. GNOME does, but output should always be in what the locale specifies (obtained by calling `nl_langinfo(CODESET)`, which is also what gettext does by default).